# Send email to admin in apex via email template with contact and account links

Tags: apex, email-template

**Use case:**

We have scenario that when a user submits form that will create account & contact record then send email to system admins. We already have this feature via custom Apex code without email templates.

**What we want:**

We want email template to control email content from admin side as we have to display two links such as account link and contact link with in the email so admin click on links directly and see details which account and contact came in our system.

**What I Already Tried & Code**

I have the below code already implemented which is sending email back to same user via template who submits the form instead admins, here in code `mail.setTargetObjectIds(lstIds);` set the same user as target email recipient, how can I set the admins as target recipient because if I set admin contact email in `mail.setTargetObjectIds();` then it will not send the relevant contact id and account id which was created due to form submission from user side.

```
public static void sendTemplateEmail() {
    List<contact> lstcon=[Select id, Email, Name from contact where Email = 'useremail@outlook.com' limit 1];
    List<Id> lstids= new List<Id>();
    for(Contact c:lstcon) {
        lstids.add(c.id);
    }
    EmailTemplate et=[Select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'TestTemplate' limit 1];
    
    Messaging.MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
    mail.setTargetObjectIds(lstIds);
    mail.setSenderDisplayName('New Contact Request!!');
    mail.setTemplateId(et.id);
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.MassEmailMessage[] { mail });
}
```

**Solution?**

What is the solution to this problem? Is this possible? Any guidance/help will be appreciated. Thank you.